# why aws assume-role-with-saml requires role and principal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml-2.0, sts-securitytokenservice

Anybody could explain why the operation assume-role-with-saml needs some parameters that are already in the saml-assertion such as role-arn and principal-arn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I'm able to answer. I was asking why send the --role-arn parameter if it is already in the saml assertion. In fact the saml assertion can have more than one role so in the api request is necessary to identify which role should be assumed. I found the answer in [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/STSMgmtConsole-SAML.html#configuring-saml-response)

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon documentation for [`assume-role-with-saml`](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role-with-saml.html) provides the information:

- The `--role-arn`*string* option **identifies** the role that the caller is assuming.
- The `--principal-arn`*string* option requires closer reading. Amazon says

> The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the SAML provider in AWS IAM that describes the **`IdP`**.
>   
>   The explanation for the latter is given a few paragraphs before:
>
> Before your application can call assume-role-with-saml , you must configure your SAML identity provider (**`IdP`**) to issue the claims required by AWS.

The same page provides a link to *[Using Identity Providers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/identity-providers.html)*, which explains the term:

> Using identity providers, you can manage user identities outside of AWS, and you can give these external user identities **permissions** to use AWS resources in your account.

That is, you could associate an external user identity with a role using the `--principal-arn` option.  The `--role-arn` option is not really *optional*, but a required parameter.

The saml-assertion (`--saml-assertion`*string)* option) is additional "glue" which may be used to check permissions.  Following the link in the description for this option to *[Configuring a Relying Party and Adding Claims](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/identity-providers-saml-configure-relying-party.html)*, Amazon says

> You also need to create appropriate claim rules in your IdP with AWS as a relying party. These rules map information about users and groups in your organization into appropriate SAML attributes. This lets you make sure that SAML authentication responses (assertions) from your IdP contain the necessary attributes that AWS uses in IAM policies to check permissions for federated users.

and in turn, that links to a page describing the assertions: *[Configure Assertions for the SAML Authentication Response](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/STSMgmtConsole-SAML.html#configuring-saml-response)*